# Bootstrap Modal not working on ios?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

The modal from bootstrap doesn't seem to work in iPhone but in Android it does.

There is data from this happening? Someone can check if this is happening on any other devices?

check here:
http://citmalumnes.upc.es/~marcelba/3r/Nuevo%20directorio/p%C3%A0gina%20principal.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is the HTML for your login link (when screen is small enough to trigger the responsive phone/tablet mode). In Chrome the cursor stays as a pointer (not hand) when I mouse over the login link in the menu:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginform">Login</a>
```

Try adding a `href` attribute so it looks like a normal link:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginform">Login</a>
```

Comment: @cvrebert notes in this SO answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354536/bootstrap-modal-window-does-not-work-on-an-ios-device) that iOS "by design" doesn't permit ordinarily non-clickable html items (like <div>) to be clickable.  I'm guessing that without the href in the <a> element, iOS takes it to be a "non-clickable" item.  For me, the simple addition of the href  worked.