# Bootstrap Modal does not work on iOS devices

Tags: html, ios, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am working on a website using Bootstrap and have a problem I can't seem to fix. Here is the [draft of the site](http://www.tbiq.com/envieta/).

On the "What We Do" panel, I made a clickable modal window on the first thumbnail box (it says "Enterprise Software development" under the thumbnail). If you click the thumbnail on a non-mobile device, a modal window will pop-up.

On a desktop computer (or laptop), it works just fine. But on a iOS (iPhone, iPad, etc.) it doesn't work at all: i.e. tapping it doesn't bring up the modal window.

However, if you look lower on the page at the "Who We are" panel, there is a "See more about Tim..." button. If you click *or tap* on that button, it will work across all devices (include iOS).

The only difference I can see between the two is that the first one is on a `<div>` tag, whereas the second one is on a `<button>` tag.

Does Bootstrap not support starting up a modal window from a `<div>` on an iOS device? If it does, do you see anything wrong with my code that would make it fail only on iOS devices?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Chris's answer is correct.  Changing the `div` to a `button` would help clarify your markup.  If, however, you need to keep the same markup, you can also add `cursor: pointer` to your div element to let safari know that this is something that might be clickable.  It also let's mouse users have a standard visual cue that the element is clickable as well.

Just add the class `clickable` and then include the following CSS:

```
.clickable {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

#### [Here's an MCVE in Fiddle with the fix as well](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/76wvpv6p/)

<sup>notice I haven't used Bootstrap's `btn` classes here because they will add the `cursor` rule automatically.</sup>

Comment: BTW, this Safari weirdness (w/ some extra details) is now documented on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click#Safari_Mobile

Comment: Thank you very much - it works!! You have saved us hours of wasted time which we would have wasted for no good reason1! Thank you once again, much appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

This isn't Bootstrap-specific at all, it's a general problem on iOS. By default, many not-usually-interactive elements (such as `<div>`s) aren't clickable/tappable on iOS.
See https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/134 and the links & follow-ups therein for some more details.
If possible, use a `<button>` or `<a>` instead. A `<div>` for an interactive element isn't very semantically appropriate anyway.