# modal not closing in iPhone 5

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, simplemodal

I have a jQuery modal with a message and a "OK" button with the class, "simplemodal-close" .

It closes the modal on desktop browsers and android devices.

It fails on iPhone 5s and iPhone 6s with iOS version 8. 
It works on those devices once the browser is minimised and brought back to view.

This is how i am opening the modal:

```
JQ('#alertPopup').modal({appendTo : '#customPop'});
```

Why does it behave like this? Any solution ?

Comment: Does your "button" have cursor: pointer; on it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354536/bootstrap-modal-does-not-work-on-ios-devices

Comment: @trainoasis Hi, I tried adding it seeing your comment. It didn't solve the issue.

Comment: i got it working finally. i changed the "button" tag to "span" and it worked. still not sure why it wouldnt work before.